# Python: How to iterate over rows that have more than one variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
tags                               views

['technology', 'science', 'art']    360
['global issue', 'energy']          670
['environment', 'technology']       800
['university', 'technology']        690
```

I used a method to find the most repeated tag (like here the most repeated tag is 'technology'). Now I want to calculate the total number of views for that tag. For example, here for 'technology', I should have the sum of 360+880+690
I should find rows in views related to that tag and sum the numbers.

How should I do that?

Comment: Sorry but the tags column looks strange. You have both, and ; and the {} normally is normally used for dictionaries. So you have strings?

Comment: The tags column has more than one variable in each row. String variables

Comment: I corrected the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

You need to iterate over rows and over keys inside summing up the corresponding values for each key.

Something like this should work:

```
from collections import Counter

input_data = (
    (('technology', 'since', 'art',), 360,),
    (('global issue', 'energy',), 670,),
    (('environment', 'technology',), 800,),
    (('university', 'technology',), 690,),
)

tag_counter = Counter()
for tags, value in input_data:
    tag_counter.update({tag: value for tag in tags})

print(tag_counter)
```

Comment: Hmmm... the question was about Pandas. Whatever, Counter will do the trick;)

Comment: I cannot understand. How it calculate the views?

Comment: And I cannot easily create input_data. I have 2000 rows in my original data frame.

Comment: 2000 rows is a bit more than nothing.
This Counter accumulates counts for each tag.
This line `tag_counter.update({tag: value for tag in tags})` sets views for each tag in a row to the value. And then Counter makes the magic.